# Why did increasing the Ackermann geometry in my race car make it faster in corners?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, drag

[Ackermann geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_steering_geometry) is used to account for the different radius arcs that the front tires follow when the steering wheel is turned from center. It's often expressed as a percentage: e.g. 25% Ackermann, 100% Ackermann.

I had observed the following physical phenomena: increasing the Ackermann geometry in my race car made it faster. Why did this work?

Comment: Hi james - this sounds a lot like a homework/educational question, which is not quite what this site is for. Could you add more detail about what you've tried yourself to figure this out, and what specific conceptual issue is giving you trouble? See our [FAQ#questions] and [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for more information.

Comment: Sure. We had noticed that mounting the steering rack on my race car and others like it about 2 inches aft made the car turn better and be faster. This effectively increases the 100% Ackerman. I'd like to know why this is. I'll restate the question to better conform to "Explanations of observed physical phenomena" per the fact.

Comment: OK, that's a bit better. If this question didn't arise in an educational context, you could remove the homework tag as well (see the [tag description](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) for some details).

Comment: Done. Not sure how it got in there; wasn't me that added it.  Thanks for your help.